# How set auto height for view in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an react native app that fetch data from an api
in this api there are news each of it contain subject, picture and details
I have problem in set the height of each item to auto height
I tried to set the height of container to 100 then the subject and details are just overlapping above each other so I set it to 300 and it's okay for the items that have long text but the problem with the items that have short text so the space between these items become too large
so how can I set the height auto so I each item will have height regarding to it's content

so this is the class of each item:

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { View, Image, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native"

export default class Item extends Component {
    render() {
        let { item } = this.props;
        const { subject, picture, details } = item;
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Image style={styles.picture} resizeMode="cover" source={{ uri: picture }} />
                {console.log(image)}

                <View style={styles.content}>
                    <Text style={styles.subject}>{subject}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.details}>{details}</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        height: 300,
        flexDirection: "row",
        flex: 1,
        padding: 10
    },
    content: {
        flexDirection: "column",
        flex: 1
    },
    picture: {
        height: 70,
        width: 100
    },
    subject: {
        marginLeft: 20,
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    },
    details: {
        marginLeft: 20,
        fontSize: 16,
    }
})
```

Comment: try diving your components using flex in you main container view

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Skip giving height to your container, and you will have dynamically required height and also remove height from your image so that it occupies the height of the final container height as per the text being rendered.

Your stylesheet should look like:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flexDirection: "row",
        //flex: 1, - remove this as this doesn't make any sense here.
        padding: 10
    },
    content: {
        flexDirection: "column",
        flex: 1,
        paddingLeft: 10, //if you need separation.
    },
    picture: {
        //height: 70, - commenting this will make it automatically ataining height as per your text grows.
        width: 100
    },
    subject: {
        marginLeft: 20,
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    },
    details: {
        marginLeft: 20,
        fontSize: 16,
    }
})
```

Comment: thanks it works now after i delete the height from container but I keep the height in picture because they stretched when commenting height  @Suraj Malviya

Comment: You should never use `cover` as resizeMode until that is needed, for simple use cases, `contain` proves to be the best option.

Comment: okay but when I set it to contain the picture is not at the top of each item but the picture now at the center of rows text so how can I make it at the top beside the subject? @Suraj Malviya

Comment: Wrap the image with a View with same style as that of Image and put Image as a child of that view with `flex:1` and `resizeMode: contain`. It should put the image on the top left. Also to align it top center, insert `alignItems: center` in the new view which i stated.

Comment: I set it like this `<View style={styles.itemNewsContainer}>
            <View style={styles.image}>
                <Image style={{flex: 1}} resizeMode="contain" source={{ uri: urlToImage }} />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.content}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.description}>{description}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.publishedAt}>{publishedAt}</Text>
                </View>
            </View>` but not work like expected

Answer (score 0):

Here in November of 2022. The solution a few people have provided is correct but needs to be reversed. If you are trying to get your  to Scroll inside of your parent  this is what worked for me

```
const windowHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height;

<View style={{height: windowHeight}}>
...
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow:1}}>...</ScrollView>
</View>
```

Hopefully this works for whoever is viewing this