# React Native - Increase view height as per text increases when keyboard open

Tags: reactjs, react-native, view, keyboard, react-native-textinput

I have created a view which has title and body. Everything works fine but when I add body and keyboard opens then text goes out of the view. Please help me as how can I increase the view height or scroll the view fully so that text must not be out of view.

**Code for view**

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
  style={{
    display: 'flex',
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
  }}
  behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}>
  <SafeAreaView
    style={{
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: !darkTheme
        ? Colors.light.f2Color
        : Colors.dark.backgrounColor,
    }}>
    {/* header */}

    {/* Post Section */}

    <View
      style={{
        width: width * 0.96,
        borderRadius: 16,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        marginTop: height * 0.01,
        flex: 0.7,
      }}>
      <View
        style={{
          backfaceVisibility: 'hidden',
          backgroundColor: !darkTheme
            ? Colors.light.backgrounColor
            : Colors.dark.cardColor,
          borderRadius: 16,
          flex: 1,
          paddingHorizontal: width * 0.02,
        }}>
        <TextInput
          style={{
            fontWeight: '300',
            fontStyle: 'normal',
            fontSize: 20,
            fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Regular',
            paddingHorizontal: width * 0.015,
            color: !darkTheme ? Colors.light.black : Colors.dark.white,
            width: '100%',
            marginTop: height * 0.02,
            flexWrap: 'wrap',
          }}
          value={postTitle}
          onChangeText={value => {
            setPostTitle(value);
          }}
          maxLength={150}
          clearButtonMode="never"
          multiline={true}
          placeholder="Add a title"
          placeholderTextColor={Colors.light.darkgrey}
        />

        <TextInput
          style={{
            fontWeight: '300',
            fontStyle: 'normal',
            fontSize: 14,
            fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Regular',
            paddingHorizontal: width * 0.015,
            color: !darkTheme ? Colors.light.black : Colors.dark.white,
            width: '100%',
            marginTop: height * 0.03,
           
          }}
          value={postBody}
          onChangeText={value => {
            setPostBody(value);
          }}
          maxLength={1000}
          clearButtonMode="always"
          multiline={true}
          placeholder="Body text"
          placeholderTextColor={Colors.light.darkgrey}
        />

        {contentType === 'Add Question' && (
          <View>
            <FlatList
              data={choiceArray}
              scrollEnabled={true}
              renderItem={({item, index}) => (
                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                  <TextInput
                    style={{
                      fontWeight: '300',
                      fontStyle: 'normal',
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Regular',
                      paddingHorizontal: width * 0.015,
                      marginTop: height * 0.025,
                      color: !darkTheme
                        ? Colors.light.black
                        : Colors.dark.white,
                      width: '90%',
                    }}
                    value={postChoices[index]}
                    onChangeText={value => {
                      addOptionValue(index, value);
                    }}
                    // onEndEditing={(value) => addOptionValue(index, value)}
                    maxLength={150}
                    clearButtonMode="never"
                    multiline={false}
                    placeholder={
                      'Option ' +
                      String.fromCharCode(97 + index).toUpperCase()
                    }
                    placeholderTextColor={Colors.light.cardOuterShadow}
                  />
                  {index > 1 ? (
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => optionCdelete(index)}>
                      <Image
                        source={require('../assets/images/red-slash.png')}
                      />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  ) : null}
                </View>
              )}
              numColumns={1}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
              contentContainerStyle={{
                backgroundColor: '#fff',
                marginTop: height * 0.02,
              }}
              showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
              onEndReachedThreshold={0}
              showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
              bounces={false}
              keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
            />

            {choiceArray.length < 4 ? (
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={addNextOption}
                style={{
                  flexDirection: 'row',
                  marginTop: height * 0.03,
                  alignItems: 'center',
                }}>
                <Image source={require('../assets/images/plus.png')} />
                <Text
                  style={{
                    color: Colors.light.darkgrey,
                    fontSize: 14,
                    fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Regular',
                    marginLeft: width * 0.01,
                  }}>
                  Add Option
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            ) : null}
          </View>
        )}

        {/* {contentType === 'Add Question' && (
          <View style={{marginTop: height * 0.02}}>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
              <TextInput
                style={{
                  fontWeight: '300',
                  fontStyle: 'normal',
                  fontSize: 14,
                  fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Regular',
                  paddingHorizontal: width * 0.015,

                  color: !darkTheme
                    ? Colors.light.black
                    : Colors.dark.white,
                  width: '99%',
                  marginTop: height * 0.015,
                }}
                value={optionA}
                onChangeText={value => {
                  setOptionA(value);
                }}
                onEndEditing={() => addChoices(optionA)}
                maxLength={150}
                clearButtonMode="never"
                multiline={false}
                placeholder="Option A"
                placeholderTextColor={Colors.light.cardOuterShadow}
              />
            </View>

            <TextInput
              style={{
                fontWeight: '300',
                fontStyle: 'normal',
                fontSize: 14,
                fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Regular',
                paddingHorizontal: width * 0.015,

                color: !darkTheme ? Colors.light.black : Colors.dark.white,
                width: '99%',
                marginTop: height * 0.025,
              }}
              value={optionB}
              onChangeText={value => {
                setOptionB(value);
              }}
              onEndEditing={() => addChoices(optionB)}
              maxLength={150}
              clearButtonMode="never"
              multiline={false}
              placeholder="Option B"
              placeholderTextColor={Colors.light.cardOuterShadow}
            />

            {surveyCount > 0 && (
              <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                <TextInput
                  style={{
                    fontWeight: '300',
                    fontStyle: 'normal',
                    fontSize: 14,
                    fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Regular',
                    paddingHorizontal: width * 0.015,
                    marginTop: height * 0.025,
                    color: !darkTheme
                      ? Colors.light.black
                      : Colors.dark.white,
                    width: '90%',
                  }}
                  value={optionC}
                  onChangeText={value => {
                    setOptionC(value);
                  }}
                  onEndEditing={() => addChoices(optionC)}
                  maxLength={150}
                  clearButtonMode="never"
                  multiline={false}
                  placeholder="Option C"
                  placeholderTextColor={Colors.light.cardOuterShadow}
                />

                {optionC.length > 0 && (
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={optionCdelete}>
                    <Image
                      source={require('../assets/images/red-slash.png')}
                    />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                )}
              </View>
            )}
            {surveyCount == 2 && (
              <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                <TextInput
                  style={{
                    fontWeight: '300',
                    fontStyle: 'normal',
                    fontSize: 14,
                    fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Regular',
                    paddingHorizontal: width * 0.015,
                    color: !darkTheme
                      ? Colors.light.black
                      : Colors.dark.white,
                    width: '90%',
                    marginTop: height * 0.025,
                  }}
                  value={optionD}
                  onChangeText={value => {
                    setOptionD(value);
                  }}
                  onEndEditing={() => addChoices(optionD)}
                  maxLength={150}
                  clearButtonMode="never"
                  multiline={false}
                  placeholder="Option D"
                  placeholderTextColor={Colors.light.cardOuterShadow}
                />

                {optionD.length > 0 && (
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={optionDdelete}>
                    <Image
                      source={require('../assets/images/red-slash.png')}
                    />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                )}
              </View>
            )}

            {surveyCount < 2 && (
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => setSurveyCount(surveyCount + 1)}
                style={{
                  flexDirection: 'row',
                  marginTop: height * 0.03,
                  alignItems: 'center',
                }}>
                <Image source={require('../assets/images/plus.png')} />
                <Text
                  style={{
                    color: Colors.light.darkgrey,
                    fontSize: 14,
                    fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Regular',
                    marginLeft: width * 0.01,
                  }}>
                  Add Option
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
          </View>
        )} */}
      </View>
    </View>
  </SafeAreaView>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

**Images of issue**

[image]

[image]

This is the issue when I am trying to add more data.Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably related to some `flex: 1` on your View containers, or a fixed height.

You can check this answer to be able to solve it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53612345/10913576